# MavenProject getDependencies Empty

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I'm working on patching a maven plugin, and after some debugging MavenProject.getDependencies() is returning dependencies when I run mvn package but no dependencies when I run mvn install.

The plugin execution is setup for package, and I'm asking for all compile dependencies.

```
@Mojo(name = "modl",
    defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.PACKAGE,
    requiresDependencyResolution = ResolutionScope.COMPILE)
```

And finally, in the project where I'm running the plugin, I do have this plugin executing under the package phase.  Is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: You must have missed something that is not in the question. `mvn install` includes `mvn package`, so if `mvn package` gives you dependencies, `mvn install` should do the same.

Comment: Yeah that's my thought as well, but doesn't seem to be the case.  When I was debugging this, I had the plugin inject the Exeuction and confirmed that it was executing during the package phase (for both mvn package and mvn install), but the getDependencies() was returning an empty set like I said.

Comment: My guess is still that you made some kind of mistake when you debugged this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it ends up I had to add an artifact filter to get this to work because it would cause a check to fail in the MavenProject class.

```
mavenProject.setArtifactFilter(new ScopeArtifactFilter("compile"));
```